# Multiple sessions accessing localhost database

Tags: database, rest, session

I do not how to ask the question, but I am confused by how to manage sessions when the server is at local host.

**Accessing the database direct**

Without a middleware (REST), sessions are created as soon as you connect to the database. Even 2 connections from same computer gets 2 separate sessions.

[image]

**Accessing via REST and localhost (127.0.0.1)**

Using a middleware, all connections goes through 127.0.0.1 and there will be only 1 single session.

[image]

Is there a way to add unique sessions connecting the database when using localhost?

Any clue to handle this is appreciated.

Comment: Does it not depends on the number of connections? DB connections are not stateless. Each connection generates a session for a given User. The same user might have different sessions depending on the number of connections created. What leads us to the driver. DB drivers use to manage connections through connection pools. It's likely your Go driver has just created only one connection. Have you tried consuming the REST service concurrently with several clients?

Comment: @laiv Direct access via tcp trigger automatically a new session. Indirect access via REST becomes one user. I do need a help to let the Go driver create sessions in some ways. I have not tried concurrently (some seconds apart though) with several clients.

Comment: `I do need a help to let the Go driver create sessions in some ways` why? This is unlikely to happen since it's contrary to the common practice of sharing connections (session) for several requests. It's a matter of efficiency.

Comment: So is this normal to only have 1 session via localhost?

Comment: Not exactly. It's common to have a limited number of concurrent connections (or sessions) per client. Your localhost could create one or more connections depending the concurrency over the REST service and the connection's pool size

Comment: @Laiv "Your localhost could create one or more connections". So it is a computer setting for localhost? Any links or how-to-do?

Comment: No. Where I say "localhost" I mean "REST service" sorry. It's not a matter of "where it runs at". Localhost, remote server, doesn't matter. It's a matter of driver configuration (mostly)

Comment: What database platform are you using? Although there is a lot of commonality.. database products from differeent vendors can have different approaches to get optimal performance, especially as you scale up.

Comment: @ Sir Swears-a-lot Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in [connection pools](http://go-database-sql.org/connection-pool.html) in Golang does the trick. Done some quick test and it seems to work.